# Is there any maximum size defined for numpy array?

Tags: numpy

If I try to execute :

```
np.empty(shape= (108698,200,1000))
```

In my jupyter notebook, it throws an error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-0aedb09803e9> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 #np.empty(shape=(108698-0,200,1000))
----> 3 np.empty(shape= (108698,200,1000))
      4 #np.empty(shape=(end-start,n_words,embedding_size))
```

But when I try to execute

```
np.empty(shape= (84323,200,1000)),
```

It executes without any errors.

So is there any way possible to run

```
np.empty(shape= (108698,200,1000))
```

without increasing the RAM of my machine?

Answer (score 2):

No.  While it depends on what you're running if you have reached you the maximum allocated memory you can't just create more.  For example, if you're running 64-bit numpy, at 8 bytes per entry, that would be 174 GB in all which would take up far too much space.  If you know the data entries and are willing to use something besides numpy you could look into sparse arrays.  Sparse arrays store only the nonzero elements and their position indices which could potentially save you space.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with arrays that do not fit into memory by using memory mapped files. Numpy has facilities for this: [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

E.g:

```
x = np.memmap('test.bin', mode='w+', shape=(108698,200,1000))
```

However, on 32 bit Python the files are still limited to 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no upper limit defined for `shape`, but the whole size of the array is limited to `numpy.intp`, which is normally `int32` or `int64`.

You can either use sparse matrix from SciPi or limit the `dtype` of your large `(108698,200,1000)` array to `int8`, which should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not upper limit. We could (roughly) estimate the amount of memory for ndarray:

```
>>> arr = np.empty(shape= (100,10,1000),dtype='unit8')
>>> hr_size(arr.nbytes)
'1M'
```

for ndarray with 1 million elements(every element of 'uint8' requires one byte) we need '976.6K' of memory.

for ndarray with  shape= (84323,200,1000) and dtype='uint8'

```
>>> hr_size(84323*200*1000)
'15.7G'
```

we need more than 15G

and finally for ndarray with shape= (108698,200,1000) and dtype='uint8'

```
>>> hr_size(108698*200*1000)
'20.2G'
```

we need more than 20G.

If dtype is 'int64' then estimated amount of memory should be increased eight times.